# Java Regex for date time

Tags: java, regex, datetime

```
Sep 25, 2013 4:51:00 PM
```

Looking to create a regex for the date time format as above
I have the following regex for the time

```
([1-9]|1[0-2]|):([0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]) (AM|am|PM|pm)
```

but can't seem to figure out the date, any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use

```
String text = "Sep 25, 2013 4:51:00 PM";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a").parse(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? I can only guess that you want to get some components from a date, so SimpleDateFormat is probably what you actually want. It is recommended to use it instead of Regular Expressions because it can also deal with locales, something that you can't do with RegExp.

**Edit:**

You should have an OR regexp for months like (Jan|Feb| ... |Dec), the rest is simple, match the space \s*, match the day [0-9]{1,2}, match a `,`, match again some space \s*, match the year [0-9]{4}, yet another space \s* and the rest of your RegExp.

Comment: I want to be able to find a date like this using regex from a html source

Comment: @user1898230 I have updated my answer, according to your needs. Beware, parsing HTML is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})
1980-02-02-05-00

Comment: This answer would be much better if you [edit] to use proper formatting for code and explain how the regex works.